# Error When I try to run react-native run-android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I'm new to react-native and i'm trying to setup a android environment on my pc. I followed the guide on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment but when I try run react-native run-android I get an error.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader

I've tried reinstalling everything, with no avail

Comment: Did you "install npm" from the root directory of the project?   You also need to do "react-native run-android"  from the root of the project.
Another thing - when you run Reactive Native app you don't do it from the "Android Studio" software.
Only after you finish the development and want to export an APK will you do so

Comment: Yeah, i've done all that. I just reinstall everything again, creating the path variables again but i still get the same error.

Comment: "creating the path variables"----What does that mean?